# Unable to connect to private AWS EKS API endpoint URL without NAT Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

We have created a completely private EKS cluster in a VPC with a private subnet only i.e. **without any NAT Gateway** through the Cloudformation template. We created an EC2 instance in the private subnet with the same role that was used to create the EKS Cluster. We created all desired VPC endpoints needed for a private EKS cluster. We have added **all allow** traffic rules to the cluster security group as well as to the outbound traffic from the EC2. Our VPC has all pre-requisites i.e. `VPC must have enableDnsHostnames and enableDnsSupport set to true, and the DHCP options set for your VPC must include AmazonProvidedDNS` still we are unable to download kubeconfig file by issuing below command

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region region-code --name my-cluster
```

Instead, we receive the below timeout error

```
Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://eks.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/clusters/<cluster-name>"
```

Please help to resolve the problem

Comment: Try maybe using the reachability analyzer on AWS to check if the connection is possible to the cluster.

Comment: Sorry, the destination is not showing as EKS in the analyzer. Can you suggest another way?

Comment: Do you have the VPC endpoints for these: `[s3, sts, ecr.api, ecr.dkr, sts, ec2]`? Also the security group for the VPC endpoints needs to allow 443 access to access the cluster endpoint

Comment: Yes, we have pre-created these endpoints along with desired traffic rules. But the EKS private endpoint is created privately which is managed by EKS internally and does not show up in the endpoints Also, the node group is able to attach to the cluster. Any more suggestions?